# Arabic Text shows in wrong-direction in Word, but not Google Docs

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, arabic

I have a word document that shows Arabic text in the wrong direction to expected.

[image]

I opened the same doc on my colleagues machine and the text shows in the correct direction.

I uploaded the doc to Google Docs, which shows it in the correct direction.

When I copy and paste the wrong-direction-text from Word into another text-editor (not word), the text becomes the right direction.

Which settings do I not have within my Word that I am missing?

Thanks

Using both the LTR and RTL buttons do not change the text direction. I recorded a clip: http://screencast.com/t/p4LIsMnBI

Comment: I have used both the Right To Left, and Left To Right buttons to no avail. They simple change the Alignment of the text, the text stays the wrong direction for both modes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved. Here's how I did it:

The Arabic language within Word had to be set as the Default language. By doing this, when pasting into Word the text was in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to RTL setting,alter it to LTR which will does the effect :

To achieve that :

1)Ensure you have arabic as language pack and enable the alternate language under

```
Start / Programs / Microsoft Office / Microsoft Office Tools / 2007 Microsoft Office system Language Settings
```

2)Navigate to `office-->word options`

3)Click on `customize`

4)Choose commands from drop-down menu, select Home Tab instead of Popular Commands

5)Find and highlight **Left-to-Right Direction**, then click the **Add** button to move it to the Customize Quick Access Toolbar section

restart the word to apply the changes

Comment: Thanks. I followed your instructions but the text direction is still incorrect. I have the Arabic Saudi Arabia language pack installed.

Comment: Using both the LTR and RTL buttons do not change the text direction. I recorded a clip: http://screencast.com/t/p4LIsMnBI